# Xamarin - WebView Pull To Refresh

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, pull-to-refresh

I've searched everywhere on google and it seems like this 'Pull To Refresh' feature is only available for `ListViews`. There are some posts regarding 'Pull To Refresh' for WebView but they are coded in Java and in Android Studio. Is there any easy way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [@jamesmontemagno's PullToRefreshLayout](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout) and include your WebView inside PullToRefreshLayout element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="RefreshSample.Views.ScrollViewXamlPage"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh;assembly=Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh"
    Title="Xaml Scroll">
   <controls:PullToRefreshLayout
          IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
          RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
          IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}"
          RefreshColor="Blue">

        <WebView>
        </WebView>

   </controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! I'll give it a try right now, I just have to install it through nuget right? And one question, how do i add that `RefreshCommand`? can u edit and show me the c# code in `MainPage.xaml.cs`?

Comment: @Denise Yes you need to install its Nuget package.Documentation and a sample project can be found in that library's GitHub page.

Comment: Sorry :( i couldn't figure it out. could u tell me how to do the binding part really quickly? im a newbie to xamarin sorry